# Embedding JavaScript code in Google sites results in error

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

I'm trying to embed a simple code in a Google site : the [source from here](http://www.feedtank.com/labs/html_canvas/) .

The code :

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>  
   <head>  
   <title>Feedtank| html 5 canvas test</title>

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="EN" />
    <meta name="Author" content="Feedtank LLC" />
    <meta name="Publisher" content="Feedtank LLC" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>



   <script type="text/javascript" src="anim.js" ></script>  

  <style type="text/css">  

   canvas { 
     border: 1px solid gray; 
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #777; 
   }

   body
     {
         background-color: #DDDDDD;
         font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, serif;
         color:#ACACA
     }

    h6{
        color:#AA8888;
        font-size:10px;
        font-family: georgia;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    h2{
        font-size:10px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        padding-left: 3px;
    }

    h4{
        color:white;
        font-size:60px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888, 1px 1px 1px #EEE;
        margin: 0px;

    }




    div#title_holder{
        width:640px;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    div#settings_holder{
        width:600px;
        border: 1px  dotted #AA8888;
        border-radius:2px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding:20px;
        overflow: auto;

    }
    input#message{
        font-size:22px;
        color: #555555;
        size: 30;
        font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, serif;
        border: 3px solid #AA8888;;
    }
    button{
        font-size:12px;
        padding:4px;
        font-family: Georgia, Verdana, Arial, serif;

    }
    li{
        list-style-type:none;padding:10px 0px 0px 3px; 
        color: #AA8888;
        font-size:14px;


    }
    ul{
    text-align: left;
    }
    h6#urlText{
        margin: 4px;
    }

    p#Options{
        color:#AA8888;
        font-size:16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 2px;
        font-family: georgia;       
    }
    div#footer{
        font-family: georgia;   
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#888888;
    }
    a{
    color:#AA8888
    }
    p#shareURL{

        font-family: georgia;   
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#888888;
    }

  </style>  

  </head>  

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper" style="width:640px; margin-left: auto ;margin-right: auto ;">

    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="title_holder">
    <h4>HTML5</h4>
    <h2>CANVAS MINIMAL PARTICLE ANIMATION DEMO </h2>
    </div>


    <canvas id="born_canvas" width="640" height="480">Missing the canvas </canvas>
    <div id="hidden_canvas" >
        <canvas id="born_canvas_hidden" width="100" height="100" style="display:none"></canvas>
    </div>

    <br>


    <p id="Options">OPTIONS</p>
    <div id="settings_holder">
    <div style="float:left; width:600px margin:5px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:0px;" >
        <input type="text"  id="message" value="Hello" maxchars="50">
        <button  value="Change message" title="change Message" onmousedown="javascript:changeMessage();"  >Change Message</button><br>
        <br>
        <p id="shareURL" style="display:inline">share url:</p>

        <h6 id="urlText">http://www.feedtank.com/labs/html_canvas/?msg=Hello</h6>


    <ul style="padding: 5px;">
        <li><input type="radio" name="radio1"  id="radio_Low" onmousedown="javascript:setMinNumCircles()"   checked="true"> 300 SPRITES</li>
        <li ><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio_High" onmousedown="javascript:setHighNumCircles()"> 1500 SPRITES (slow framerate)</li>
        <li ><input type="checkbox" name="gravity" id="bGravity" onmousedown="javascript:setGravity()" > GRAVITY</li>
        <li ><input type="checkbox" name="gravity" id="bGravity" onmousedown="javascript:setFade()" checked="true" > FADE</li>
    </ul>

    </div>



    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="footer">
        Feb 4th, 2010 | Created By <a href="http://www.feedtank.com">Feedtank</a> 
    </div>

  </body>  

  </html>
```

But when I try to run the code in W3SCHOOL [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro) , it results in error :

[image]

What am I doing wrong then ?

Comment: your site works, why do you want it displayed in the W3School page anyway? It will not help you in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows error because your anim.js path is false

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="anim.js" ></script>
```

and  image are also not avilable ,so please properly put all your supporting files in your project folder and then run ,don't try in w3schools